# Django admin site seems to ignore custom UserCreationForm

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django project `Project`, in which I am trying to include custom user information with a `UserProfile` model. I have created a custom `StackedInline`, `UserCreationForm`, and `UserAdmin` to add this information when a user is created, but the form in the Django admin site appears unaffected.

```
# Commons/admin.py

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'


class UserProfileCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone = forms.RegexField(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        error_messages={'invalid': "Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed."},
        required=True
    )
    phone2 = forms.RegexField(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        error_messages={'invalid': "Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed."},
        required=False
    )
    address = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
        user = super(UserProfileCreationForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_profile = UserProfile(
            user=user,
            phone=self.cleaned_data['phone'],
            phone2=self.cleaned_data['phone2'],
            address=self.cleaned_data['address']
        )
        user_profile.save()
        return user, user_profile


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    add_form = UserProfileCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'phone', 'phone2', 'address')
    }),
)

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

I have the `Commons` app registered in `INSTALLED_APPS`, is there something else I'm missing?

edit:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/?', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^jwt-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Commons\index.html"), name='base')
]
```

Comment: Please show us your project's URL config (`urls.py`).

Comment: Not sure how that factors in, but I've included it.

Comment: I was thinking you might need to have `admin.autodiscover()`, but on reflection don't think that should be necessary unless you're using a custom admin class. Can't see what else the issue could be.

Comment: @Magrias I'm having the same issue, apparently. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @FlipperPA I did not, the problem ended up compounding with some other issues and the project completely stalled.